# How to know thread alive not from the outside of thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm using `thread` on my program. I wants to know thread still alive or not from the out side of thread.

Note:thread working in long process,
     I need the return value from the thread,
     if thread end it'll report.
how to do?????????

thanks.

Comment: Thread.IsAlive https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [IsAlive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive(v=vs.110).aspx) Property of your Thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
t.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Still alive: " + t.IsAlive);
```

Comment: hey body it's my mistake. thread working in long process while finish the job then i wants check  thread alive or not

Comment: @PandiyanT so you don't have a reference to the thread you want to check? You could just iterate over the threads of your process and find it by name.

Or could you explain again what you want to do?

Comment: You could create an event which will be called from your "long running" thread and listen to it on mainthread. So the mainthread will be notified and you can pass your result to the mainthread. If you want to change something on the mainthread, you have to invoke it.

Comment: main thread means what i mean i'm using this thread in asp.net so you mean WebUI is the main thread. right..?????.

Comment: Right, the "main" thread is the one which started the other one.